# Is it possible to make a jumper with MOSFET?

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, switches

I have a PCB where two signals can be connected with a jumper. These two signals are neither GND nor VCC.

The problem is that switching between the unconnected and connected mode requires a user intervention (ie. setting the jumper or removing it). I would like to replace this "mecanical" switch with an electronical switch. I was thinking of using MOSFET controlled by a microcontroller.

Is it possible ? Is there a simple schematic to do this ?

Thanks. :)

Comment: Please provide a bit more information on what type of signal this jumper provides a path for. Is it ACc DC, sound, analog or digital? What is the concrete use case?

Answer (score 1):

The [CD4016](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4016b.pdf) is a CMOS quad bilateral switch. This would work if your signals are between 0 and about 15 V.

[image]

*Figure 1. Switching a CONTROL pin high connects the associated IN/OUT pins.*

Check the series on-resistance of the switch. It may be a couple of hundred ohms and this may affect your circuit. I seem to remember that the CD4066 had a lower on-resistance.

Comment: If the on-resistance is too high, a relay would work as well.